# Tranfer attribute into a new element

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, transfer

First of all I hope I will be understood.

I have this:

```
       <item>
             <ptr target="X"/>BlahBlah
       </item>
```

And I would like to convert it into this:

```
    <li>
        <a href="X">Blahblah</a>
    </li>
```

All I could do was create this:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:ptr">
        <li>
            <a>
                <xsl:value-of select="parent::node()"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
```

But the result wasn't the one I was waiting for:

```
<li>
      <a>BlahBlah</a>
</li>BlahBlah
```

I could change the elements I wanted but the content of the `<item>` element was displayed twice, and I ignore the way to display the href attribute. If required I can show my entire XSL sheet.

I searched through the stackoverflow without result, maybe I just don't know how to put my problem into words.

Could someone help and explain how it does work? I know I have  little understanding of XSLT, but I'm trying.

Thank you very much for your answer,

Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is:

```
<xsl:template match="//item/text()">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != ''">
        <li>
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="../ptr/@target" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
            </xsl:element>
        </li>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

which results in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<li>
    <a href="X">BlahBlah</a>
</li>
```

You might replace the `//item` with a relative path to the `item` element if appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Works perfectly